# Logging App events/exceptions/messages in Enterprise Environnments

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, citrix

We've been having a discussion in our office as part of an upgrade of an old application from VB6 to .Net 3.5 about how best to approach logging. The old system used local log files, the path for which was contained in the registry (with a default should one not be specified). Most of us are now leaning towards using the Windows Application Event Log, however one guy raised a question which stopped us dead.

What about environments like Citrix where load balancing means that one users' session might be served by different app servers at different points? We suddenly potentially have fragments of info from a session spread across several servers (or so we believe - most of us haven't had to deal with this before so we're not 100% sure) which makes it hard for the support guys to piece together the chain of events during a support call. The general consensus seems to be that we should use the MS Enterprise Library logging abilities and set up a central repository of logs for each installation.

Can anyone recommend a best practice or sensible approach to application logging in multiple environments including app server farms, other than centralised logs using Enterprise Library, or are we already on the right track?

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, they were all good info so I've voted them all up (no real right or wrong here). Accepted Helge Klein's answer as they put my mind at rest about the handling of session in Citrix. I think we will probably go for centralised logs using Enterprise Library as this seems to be the easiest approach to implement and also the most sensible in terms of ease of support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Citrix farms, load balancing is performed per session (before logon). Individual sessions cannot be moved between servers. The latter incidentally being the "holy grail" of server-based computing - if you figure it out, tell Citrix how to do it, they WILL be interested ;-)

That should make it simpler for you. In all Windows environments a session is always on the same physical respectively virtual machine. With that information, logging to the event log has become an option again.

Comment: I have to say, I did wonder when the guy in question said about sessions being split across different servers - seemed a bit far fetched but since I've no experience of Citrix I couldn't comment either way! Sounds like  we were heading in the right direction anyway by using Enterprise Library and centralising logs. Perhaps we should look into writing some sort of simple viewer or macro which filters out stuff for our app from the windows logs which is then search-able based on user ids/session ids.

Answer (score 1):

Normally I'm all about using the built in windows logging functions for desktop apps and services.  However, this raises an interesting problem.

I think that you'll be better served by leveraging Enterprise Library and centralize your log storage.

Answer (score 1):

We use a custom TraceListener class that writes the logs to a centralized database.

Comment: Would love to do this, but typically for a commercial outfit, we have to go with bang-for-buck solutions and we already have some file logging in place, and I doubt I could persuade the money men of the benefits of this approach, much as I'd love to!!

Answer (score 1):

Even the Event Log can work in your situation - you just have to include something like an Activity ID and/or Session ID. With this, you will be able to correlate all the pieces of the application log.

Logging to a central database can help, in that all the pieces can be in a single place. However, you should still look into the use of an Activity ID.

See the [CorrelationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager.aspx) class.